# Angular router does not route if returned as Rxjs observable in Resolver

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

In my angular app i'm using a resolver that in the method resolve returns an observable of promise. (true (routed) or false (routing failed))

In the version of rxjs6 the function "Observable.fromPromise" is replaced by "from" that looks for promise type/instance and will handle as one.

<s>Why did i have another behavior in rxjs6 with "from", In the under example the router will not navigate to 'home', it seems that the promise doesn't emit/end</s>

If i return it as Observable it will not route, to the given link, if i call it without evaluating the return value it works.

Example:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  resolve(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return from(this.router.navigate(['/home'])); // not working
    // return Observable.fromPromise(this.router.navigate(['/home'])); works
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you done `import { from } from 'rxjs';` ?

Comment: yes, it's imported, i'm debugging now to see where the problem is.

Comment: Okay - I tried your example with simple Promise object - and it works fine for me.

Comment: I made a easier example of my problem, the result is that when i place from(Promise.resolve(true))); instead of from(this.router.navigate(['/home'])); it's working, i think the angular router makes problems, it's in a lazy loaded module.

Answer (score 0):

Either do it this way

```
return Observable.from(this.router.navigate('/home'));
```

or import from

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
```